# Triangles are drawn out of (depth) order

Tags: three.js, webgl

I am trying to create a simple example with three.js. I have a bunch of triangles making up a volume. It seems triangles are incorrectly ordered -- or rendered in weird order. Here is the example you can see:

http://urlmin.com/qlp

just rotate the view around and see the view flickering.

The behavior is same with canvas or webgl renderer.

Please note that I am not using lights. Each triangle is colored slightly differently.

I must be missing something really simple. Let me know you think. Thanks!

Comment: What means are you trying to use to produce a correct render?  Are you trying to use a z-buffer or something like painter's algorithm?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are drawing all of the triangles individually rather than consolidating them into one geometry objet? Performance-wise this is a really bad way of approaching this problem, especially if you are using the WebGL renderer since a new shader program would be called for every single triangle, every frame. You should consider consolidating all your triangles into a single Geometry object and colouring the triangles independently using vertex colours.

Comment: @DonCruickshank: No, I simply want to render a solid volume made up of triangles.

Comment: @wagerfield: right, thanks for the suggestion, I will do that. because of this rendering problem, I have been trying it in many different ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/aR8wr/

Your camera NEAR plane is very small and FAR plane very big. This results in less precision in rendering, floating point errors, and thus, flickering. Setting those variables to for example 0.01 and 1000 gets rid of the flickering.

It still looks weird from some angles. I'm not exactly sure what causes it, but it might help if you divide your model into smaller triangles. Alternatively, you can use WebGLRenderer, where it works perfectly as long as you set more sensible values to NEAR and FAR.

Comment: thanks!! webgl works perfect now. I still have to find a solution for the canvas renderer -- can't really assume that browsers support webgl. It should be a pretty simple thing to do and should work with canvas just fine also.